# Returning a javascript object from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

We are returning the following JSON from a ruby code:

```
{
 "label":"CPU-7",
 "data":[[50,45,38,34]],
 "settings":{
            "seriesDefaults":{
                             "renderer":"$.jqplot.BarRenderer"
                             },
            "axes":{
                   "xaxis":{
                           "renderer":"$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer",
                           "ticks":[50,45,38,34]
                           }
                   }
            }
}
```

However, "$.jqplot.BarRenderer" is an object and we don't want it to be returned as string, is there a way to do this?

Comment: encode $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer as a json object?

Comment: Copy from my answer below: The data we are returning is basically a hash and has to be converted to JSON. What we want is for that particular part of the json not to be quoted as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question but gives an alternative.  See my note below though if you absolutely must do what you're wanting

You probably don't want your ruby code to know anything about your javascript objects.  Rather you can maintain some sort of `type` structure such that if you returned data is of type `barChart` you can reference it that way.  SOmething like:

```
var chartTypes = {
  barChart: $.jqplot.BarRenderer
}
```

Then if you returned:

```
{"settings":{
  "seriesDefaults":{
    "type": "barChart"
  }
}
```

You can use

```
chartTypes[settings.seriesDefaults.type]
```

Again, I'd avoid having your ruby know anything about your javascript objects or how you're actually rendering the data.  Ruby should just provide the data, javascript chooses what to do with it.

**note**

to get an actual object from your json string, just do

```
// not recommended!!!
var obj = eval(settings.seriesDefaults.renderer);
```

Comment: Thanks, we have actually made a solution similar to your answer, that is to map the retuned string to a type in javascript. My initial objective was to actually avoid it and pass the returned data from ruby code directly to a javascript function. It was a long shot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try raw method in your view. It will render the data as it is.

```
<%= raw @data%>
```

Upadte:

Are you rendering data in controller like this?

```
render :json => @data.to_json
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My mistake, I should've been more clear. The data we are returning is basically a hash and has to be converted to JSON. What we want is for that particular part of the json not to be quoted as string.

Comment: Can you post the view part where u access response??

Comment: It is actually a js function: `$.jqplot(targetDiv, data[0].data, data[0]settings);` data is the json returned from ruby (using $.ajax() function)

Comment: Everything seems fine. Now its not easy to solve this through forum :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible. JSON is a simple hash, and ruby can not include javascript object, and there is no way (afaik) to `eval` parts of the JSON.

So i would suggest something similar, and let the server render a  `chart.js.erb` instead of JSON, and place the inside the partial you write the complete `$.jqplot` function.